# Does the Orthodox Church accept the Athanasian Creed?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, nicene-creed, athanasian-creed

One of the main points of debate between the Eastern and Western churches concerns the words "[and the Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filioque)" in the Nicene Creed's description of the Holy Spirit.

The so-called Athanasian Creed includes the words "and the Son" when describing the Holy Spirit.

How does the Orthodox Church view the Athanasian Creed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the Orthodox, there is precisely one Creed: the Niceno-Constantinopolitan Creed.

That being said, it depends on what you mean by 'accept'.  The theology of *Quicunque Vult* / (Pseudo-)Athanasian Creed is definitely Latin in origin, but, generally speaking, it is theologically acceptable to the Orthodox once the *filioque* is removed. It is occasionally included in Russian psalters without the *filioque*. For example, [see here](http://www.orthodox.net/journal/2009-11-11_athanasian-creed+russian-orthodox-psalter+mystery.html) for a ROCOR view.

However, *Quicunque Vult* is not considered normative in Orthodoxy. It is a useful historic document of the Church, but it was never endorsed (or to my knowledge, mentioned) by an Ecumenical Council. It is not creed.

Most of this is [covered by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasian_Creed).